# Preselect a MySQL populated Dropdown List with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a form which will be filled with data from a mysql table:

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "user", "pass");
        mysql_select_db("db",$db);
        $sql = "Select * from wp_awa_upload where uid = '$_SESSION[id]' and project = '$_SESSION[project]'";
        //echo $sql;
        $ergebnis = mysql_query($sql); 
        $row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis);

        $category = $row->cat;
```

The variable $category contains the name of the Category the user previously has entered.

in this form I have a Dropdown List which will be populated with data from a mysql Table:

```
<? $db = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("db",$db); mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'"); $sql = "SELECT cat FROM subcategory order by cat asc";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='parent_cat'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['cat'] . "'>" . $row['cat'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>"; ?>
```

The Dropdown contains ALL the selectable Categories. What I now want to achieve is to Highlight (or set to position 1) the $category in the Dropdown.

Something like

```
if ($row['cat'] == $category) { 

echo '<option value="'.$row['cat'] .'" selected="selected">'.$row['cat'] .'</option>'; } else {

echo '<option value="'.$value.'" selected="selected">'.$value.'</option>';

} 

echo "</select>"; ?>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your support!

Kind Regards,

Stefan

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a ternary operator like so:

```
<option value="<?= $row['cat']; ?>" <?= $row['cat'] == $category ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
```

The ternary operator checks true or false. The first option after the '?' is true and the second option after the ':' is false. If the row you are iterating through equals what you are trying to set as selected then php will echo out 'selected'.

Also, you notice I changed the styling a bit. A best practice in php is to let html be html and php to be php. Notice how I echoed the value and the ternary statement instead of echoing out the entire html block.

So following that here is your code from above:

```
<?php 
$db = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("db",$db); mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
$sql = "SELECT cat FROM subcategory order by cat asc";
$result = mysql_query($sql); ?>

<select name='parent_cat'>
 <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
 <option value="<?= $row['cat']; ?>" <?= $row['cat'] == $category ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>
   <?= $row['cat']; ?>
 </option>
 <?php } ?>
</select>
```

You can see that it is much easier to identify the php from the html and vice versa.